# Video mixer filter

Tags: c++, directshow

I need to find a video filter in order to mix multiple video streams (let's say, maximum 4).
I've found a video mixer filter from MediaLooks and is ok, but the problem is that i'm trying to use it in a school project (for the entire semester) and so the 30 days trial is kind of unacceptable.

So my question to you is that: are you aware of a free direct show filter that could help. If this is not working then it means i must write one. The problem here is that i don't know from where to start.

Comment: I ended up by implementing the filter. Things worked out great because the specifications grew up and I had a flexible filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up by implementing my own filter.

Comment: Well done! I have a similar problem. I've written numerous tranform filters, but they all have one input pin and one output pin. To handle multiple input pins, did you just process each frame as it came in on each pin, or did you wait for pairs of frames, one on each pin, before mixing?

Answer (score 1):

If you need output to the display, you can use the VMR. If you need output to file, then I think you will need to write something. The standard solution to this is to write an allocator/presenter plugin for the VMR that allows you to get back the mixed video and then save it somewhere. This is more efficient that a fully software-only mixer filter.

G

Answer (score 0):

The VideoMixerRender9 (and 7) will do the trick for you.  You can set the opacity and area each video going into the VMR9.  I suggest playing with it from within graphedit.

I would also like to suggest skipping that all together.  If you use WPF, you will get far more media capabilities, much easier.

If you want low level DirectShow support, you can try my project, [WPF Mediakit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com).  I have a  control called MediaUriElement that is similar to WPF's MediaElement.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but the problem is that I need to add more filters after i mix the videos. So if the VMR would have an output pin that would indeed be great.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I just looked up the MediaLooks mixer and I think have a better idea of what you are doing.  There are no free mixers I'm aware of that will do this.  Making your own requires you to make a _transform_ filter.  Not bad if you are familiar with COM and C++.  Try the DShow Wizard from here:  http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm It's for VS2003, but you may be able to shoe-horn it in to later version.  It really helped me get started...

Comment: Also what filters do you need to add after the mixer?  Does it get streamed out/written to a file or does it just get rendered to the screen?

Comment: After this filter i'm using a SampleGrabber and also am SmartTee filter and just later a VideoRender. Thanks for your interest.